# Error executing "npm run" in fresh laravel file - Cannot find module npm-cli.js

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js

Can someone help me on this? I'm getting error below when executing the `npm run` on my fresh laravel project.

- I've installed new laravel file `larave new vue-lar-proj`
- then installed modules `npm install`
- then immediately tried to execute `npm run watch` I'm getting error below.

[image]

But when I tried installing the laravel file using this command

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel vue-lar-proj "5.5.*"`

I've got no problem executing the `npm run watch`.

I only get the error on `npm run dev` and `npm run prod`

I'm new on this, appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Is `npm-cli` installed globally?

Comment: which version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: @Tarasovych how do I know `npm-cli` was not installed globally? But i think it was global cause as I've installed my nodejs. I did not change anything, just click next.

Comment: @MohammadIstanboli when i use the command `laravel new vue-lar-proj` it will install the latest version of laravel which is 5.6 but when I use the `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel vue-lar-proj "5.5.*"` it will install the 5.5

Comment: Hello, I've already solved the problem. i found out that the "node_modules" folder was not in the "C:\Users\Jun Rey\AppData\Roaming\npm". So I run the command `npm install npm --global` and it create the folder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I found out that `node_modules` folder did not exist. So I created this folder by:

`$ npm install`

I didn't install `npm-cli` globally. So tried to install `npm-cli`:

`$ npm install npm-cli`